# Windows 10 Insider Preview USB Setup Installation Issue

Tags: usb, windows, lubuntu

I have an HP Envy laptop which came pre-installed with Windows 8. Eventually it became slow, so I decided to restore it and I lost my Windows key in the process. Instead of using an unlicensed Windows, I decided to get Lubuntu since it is free and fast. Now however, I would like to try Windows 10. I have downloaded the Windows 10 Insider Preview and made it bootable onto a USB. Upon booting up the Windows 10 Insider Preview via USB, it begins to start the setup process. However, an error occurs and reads as the following: "No device drivers were found." Any help is greatly appreciated on solving this issue.

Answer (score 3):

If your laptop came pre-installed with Windows, it can most likely be restored via recovery partition (unless you deleted it while formatting with Lubuntu). All Windows 8 devices are poised to get free Windows 10 upgrade a few weeks from now. Besides, Microsoft has told users not to clean install insider builds of windows 10 as it won't get activated.

http://www.neowin.net/news/psa-now-is-not-a-good-time-to-do-a-clean-windows-10-install

So, I'd suggest you wait for official launch of Win 10 and upgrade from within Win 8 to avoid any potential trouble from Win 10 preview builds.
If you perform a clean install of Win 8/8.1 on your laptop, you won't need a key.
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/where-do-i-find-the-windows-8-product-key-when-it/

Answer (score 1):

An error message during Windows 10 Insider Preview installation is your least concern, registration for this program is closed for now, new installations will not get activated. You need to get Windows 8 back onto your device and in order to take advantage of the Windows 10 upgrade offer that will be available in a few days.

Call your HP customer support representative, tell them what happened to your Windows installation and ask them what could be done about that.